# Should I use 'is' or 'are' in this context?

Tags: grammaticality

I am writing a paper and my editor indicates this sentence as having wrong grammar:

> Thus, it is no surprise that forecasting bond returns is a major topic
> in financial literature.

It suggests using:

> Thus, it is no surprise that forecasting bond returns are a major
> topic in financial literature.

This sound wrong to me, but I want to be sure. Is my editor wrong? Can someone explain which is the correct structure and why?

Comment: Your editor is incorrect. I wonder what it would say if you typed *predicting bond returns...*?

Comment: Your editor is wrong and weird. Forecasting is a singular noun!

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, assuming that you mean 'the practice of forecasting bond returns is...'

The editor seems to interpret 'forecasting' as a term describing the (plural) bond returns.

Comment: I think the editor, who is probably a computer program, thinks that “returns” is the subject of the clause.